# Semantic URL Custom Post Type and Taxonomies permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have created a custom post type with custom taxonomies. Now I need help with the permalinks.

Now is like that:

- custom post type archive: `example.com/custom-post-type/`
- taxonomy archive: `example.com/taxonomy/`
- single custom post type: `example.com/custom-post-type/single/`

It should be like that:

- custom post type archive: `example.com/custom-post-type/`
- taxonomy archive `example.com/custom-post-type/taxonomy/`
- single custom post type: `example.com/custom-post-type/taxonomy/single/`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: for single custom post type, do you mean /cpt/term/single/, or do you want the name of the taxonomy there?

Comment: That's right. The URL will be /CPT/TERM/SINGLE/

Comment: Are you using just one taxonomy?

Comment: No, there'll web seven or eight taxonomies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Plugin Recommendation

I've had some great experience with the plugin [Custom Post Type Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/).

Here's the settings panel that it provides which allows you to define your structure per custom post type.

[image: Custom Post Type Permalinks Admin]

### Adding More Permalink Tags

If you want to further extend the permalink structure tags for your needs you can take a look at the [add_rewrite_tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag) API function.

### CTP Tax Archive

The CPT Permalinks plugin won't take care of your CPT Tax archive, so you need to add the following rewrite rule to your functions.php file:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^(your-cpt)/(taxonomy_1|taxonomy_1|taxonomy_3)/?','index.php?post_type=$matches[1]&taxonomy=$matches[2]','top');
```

You will obviously need to replace your-cpt and the taxonomy names in the regex.

### Testing

I highly recommend you to use the [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) to help understand what rewrites are registered and how they match your URLs.

Hope this helps you out.